# 2003 Toyota Camry 300 rpm with AC on

Tags: ac, idle

I have a 2003 Toyota Camry 4 cylinder with the AC  on it runs at 300 rpm and stalls. What could be my problem and is there anyways to adjust the idle?

Comment: Have you done any reparation/maintenance on this car lately?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely a stuck A/C VSV (Vacuum Switching Valve).  It's supposed to activate to increase the idle when the A/C compressor starts.  When it fails you'll have crazy low RPM idle when running the A/C.

Normally the A/C VSV is pretty easy to locate for pulling out and testing.  Factory repair manual will have the test procedure (normally just apply the correct voltage and do a puff test to see if air flows/doesn't flow per specification).

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar sounding issue with an old prelude I had. Does the car idle fine if the AC is off? It could be that the AC has seized and is running on the same belt as the engine, so when the AC runs it is causing restriction for the engine belt to run and in turn killing the engine.

Answer (score 0):

I would first clean the throttle body. If that does not work, replace the idle air control valve.